# How to integrate Bootstrap-Modals in Angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, angular6, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I want my button to open a modal as it is click.

This is the button.
[image]

And the modal is opening like this in the bottom of the page:

[image]

Here is my HTML and modal code:

[image]

[image]

And here is my component.ts:

[image]

I am referring ng-bootstrap here:
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Comment: Please add some sample code to work with(not images of code). It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can use [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) to create one.

Answer (score 1):

why are you using bootstrap modal when using angular? there are lots of good frameworks out there such as Angular material that are completely Compatible with angular.

you can see angular material documentation here for popup windows:

[dialog in angular material](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)

and you can see a full documentation for getting started with angular material here:

[angular material](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

importing angular material into your project takes 5 minutes and it is highly recommended. it has a really great pack of useful components.

by the way, angular material is developing by angular team, and is fully integrated with angular.